# Equivalent of "One man's trash is another man's treasure"?

Tags: идиомы

is there a russian equivalent to that idiom?

Edit:
The meaning is not literal but, typically, a commentary on how there is no judging for taste — what one person may think is worthless may be cherished by another.

For example, someone might want to throw out their old clothes, which are trash to them, but another person might want those clothes, e.g. for arts and craft. those clothes are therefore treasure

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Could you please clarify the meaning of this idiom and provide a couple of examples of its usage (in English)? This will help those not familiar with it give you a better answer. Thanks!

Comment: Что русскому хорошо, то немцу(meaning a foreigner) смерть.

Answer (score 12):

Can't think of anything having quite that meaning but by way of extrapolation the following might work

> **Кому война, а кому мать родна**

which means that someone's misfortunes are someone else's luck.

[Multitran](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=One+man%27s+trash+is+another+man%27s+treasure) doesn't give any natively Russian equivalents either aside from another extrapolated proverb

> **Что русскому хорошо, (то) немцу смерть**

Both are based on contrast in experience like the English one.

Still if all else fails literal translation will do

> **Что для одного - (му)сор, (то) для другого - клад/сокровище**
>   **Одному (му)сор - другому клад/сокровище**
>   **Кому (му)сор, а кому (и) клад/сокровище**

Or we may try to make it sound like a proverb since many of them rhyme

> **Что одним не надо, тому другие рады**
>   **Что одним не надо, то другим - награда**
>   **Что тебе не надо, то мне - награда**
>   **Тебе не надо, а мне - награда**

and license it under CC0

And for lulz the version of Google Translate

> **Мусор одного человека - это еще одно мужское сокровище**

Answer (score 3):

Another version which I think is canonical translation is "**На вкус и цвет товарища нет**". It is translates to: "You can't find a friend judging by someones preferences in taste and color".

There is a humorous version: "**На вкус и цвет все фломастеры разные**". Translation: "Judging by taste and color all felt-tip pen are different". Not sure about "felt-tip pen".